# How to fix import error in JavaScript: 'file name differs from already included file name in casing' while using Components.js in Tooltip.js

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about how to use import and export - the modules.
I have a file named - Components.js in a folder with other files.
Now when I import it in other file (named - Tooltip.js), it shows error which says -
The file name differs from already included file name in casing'.

The problem is that I have only one file with name = Components.js (with capital C) as I mentioned.
`import { Component } from "./Components.js"` - Vs Code also shows the correct path but when entered there's an error in the script - it won't accept this path.

How do I fix this - how do I get the correct file name?

And to solve that error - I have to write './components.js'(with lowercase C) to import it.
It worked but I don't have file with name components.js!

Comment: What is the actual name of the file?

Comment: This could be a deed of some tool or extension. In windows file names are case insensitive

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Component.js is  the actual name of the file.

Comment: But I got the solution - the error was on my part. I write all the notes on a notes.js file. There I also type in the code that I'm taught. So when the lecture's done I copy the code that was taught and paste it on the main files(project) that uses these code - that's where I get the problem, I have to manually type in the file path name rather than pasting it from another file. So when I erased the pasted path name & typed in manually with ./ and so on, the error disappeared. Everything worked.